# Rollback error when restoring SQL dump file in postgresql using PSQL console via Pgadmin

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mapserver

I am trying to restore a `pg_dump` SQL file into my postgresql database using PSQL console , where I typed the below command:

\i 'c:/../path/to/sample.sql'

when I run this I get an error saying transaction is aborted and ends with ROLLBACK.

Can anyone please let me know the reason for this error?

Comment: Show the first error using `\set ON_ERROR_STOP on` then re-run the script. Other errors (if any) are usually noise.

Comment: no function matches the given name and argument types. you might need to add explicit type casts

Comment: It also says function addgeomerticcolum does not exist

Comment: The error is in your last comment. You need to install PostGIS to the database.

Comment: Thanks. I see I did not install POSTGis in window. However I have linux system which I have connected remotely and I am not able to use $psql2shp command in the command line. I went to /usr/local/pgsql/data to run the command but I was unable to run. I dont have permission to set env variable. Where should I be running psql2shp command?

Answer (score 1):

To investigate an error in a script file with psql, it may help to identify the first error by stopping the script on the first error with:

```
\set ON_ERROR_STOP on
```

This is off by default, which is why you might see repeated noise messages "ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block"

---

With an error like:

```
psql:C:/path/to/my_layer.sql:13: ERROR:  function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unkn
own, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AddGeometryColumn('','my_layer','geom','0','MULTIPOL...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to
add explicit type casts.
```

This generally means that PostGIS needs to be installed on the database, using something like:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```